# How to create a list of values from cell, separated by certain characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list that looks something like this

[image]

What I want to do is create a formula so in another cell I get the following

'ID1','ID2',ID3','ID4'

It doesn't matter if at the very beginning and at the very end I get extra characters because I can remove those manually, my issue is that in reality this list has hundred of IDs and I can't do this manually.

Comment: If you have Excel 365, use TEXTJOIN https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c

Comment: This is asked before (data in this exact format). Was it not you? `TEXTJOIN()` is your go-to function here.

Answer (score 1):

In next column (assuming data starting in A1):
in B1 `= " ' " & A1 & " ' "` and drag down (I added spaces to make readable, but you don't want them within the quotes in your actual formuale)
Then in C1 `= B1`, and in C2 `= C1&","&B2`, and drag down.